# How to: Give permissions for text channel when user joins VC and revoke when user leaves VC

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to make it so that when someone joins the Voice Channel, so the Bot will add the specific person to the text channel with the permission to read and send messages and remove the individual and their permissions when they leave the Voice Channel. I'm not overly familiar with discord.js so I'm not sure on how to do it.

Comment: Remember that if you're going to ask a how-to question, sometimes code isn't required, but at least a link to the API, or some more chunk in your question would help :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, welcome to Stack Overflow. I hope we can be of help to you.

Let's start by detecting when a member joins a voice channel. To do so, we can listen to your client's [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event. Next, we can compare the old voice channel with the new one, and see if the member joined or left. Finally, we can change the permissions for the member in the text channel using [`GuildChannel.overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions).

**Update:** Multiple "pairs" of text channels and voice channels with similar behavior.

To do this for many different channels, you could set up a json file to store the voice channels and corresponding text channels, and then iterate over each pair, checking if the situation matches any.

`channelPairs.json`

```
[
  { "voice": "voiceChannelIDHere", "text": "textChannelIDHere" }
]
```

`index.js`

```js
const pairs = require('./channelPairs.json'); // Keep in mind the path may vary

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let oldID;
  let newID;
  if (oldMember.voiceChannel) oldID = oldMember.voiceChannel.id;
  if (newMember.voiceChannel) newID = newMember.voiceChannel.id;

  for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    const textChannel = newMember.guild.channels.get(pairs[i].text);
    if (!textChannel) {
      console.log('Invalid text channel ID in json.');
      continue;
    }

    const vcID = pairs[i].voice;

    if (oldID !== vcID && newID === vcID) {          // Joined the voice channel.
      textChannel.overwritePermissions(newMember, {
        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
        SEND_MESSAGES: true
      }).catch(console.error);
    } else if (oldID === vcID && newID !== vcID) {   // Left the voice channel.
      textChannel.overwritePermissions(newMember, {
        VIEW_CHANNEL: null,
        SEND_MESSAGES: null
      }).catch(console.error);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd like to ask, how would you go about doing this for multiple states? What I mean is for another VC and text channel link. How would I go about having multiple pairs like that?

Comment: @AzureReckoning Great question. I'll update the code to show a simple way.

Comment: @AzureReckoning Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Okay so let's take a look at the DiscordJS API:**

Found [here.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

As we can see, there's a class called "*WSEvent*" (stands for *WebsocketEvent*). We can use this to detect when a user joins the channel...

But we can't really use that because there's no "CHANNEL_JOIN" event. So instead, we must listen for this voiceStateUpdate or VOICE_STATUS_UPDATE event.

Like so:

```
// voiceStateUpdate
/* Emitted whenever a user changes voice state - e.g. joins/leaves a channel, mutes/unmutes.
PARAMETER    TYPE             DESCRIPTION
oldMember    GuildMember      The member before the voice state update
newMember    GuildMember      The member after the voice state update    */
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", function(oldMember, newMember){
    console.log(`a user changes voice state`);
  // Here we can just check if newMember is in the channel that we want. Bam.
  if(newMember.voiceChannel.name == 'channelname') {
    // DO SOMETHING.
    myVoiceChannel.overwritePermissions(newMember, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: true
    });
  } else {
    myVoiceChannel.overwritePermissions(newMember, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: null
    });
  }
});
```

Let's reduce this:

`newMember.voiceChannel` - This means what channel their connected to.

`voiceChannel.name` - Get the name of the channel so we can check it.

Hope I was a help, and by the way, here's a neat little cheatsheet I like to use when developing DiscordJS bots: https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584

Comment: Downvoting for two reasons. Number one, this answer doesn't address the permissions part of the question. Number two, the code is off the rails. `newUser` is not defined. `voiceConnections` is a property of a Client instance, not a GuildMember. The proper code would look like `newMember.voiceChannel.name`. Even with this fix, the code will still be triggered by a user muting or unmuting themselves, etc.

Comment: OOF. My brain was rattled when I answered that. I will make the proposed fixes, but I believe you're wrong about the muting/unmuting. "e.g. joins/leaves a channel"

Comment: Direct quote from the docs: "Emitted whenever a user changes voice state - e.g. joins/leaves a channel, **mutes/unmutes**."

Comment: I don't think it would matter because there's a clear if statement that would make a check. Just because a mute fires the event, doesn't change the end effect that when in the channel they will have the permissions, and luckily overwritePermissions also will not save the permissions. So all is fine? What's the problem here... And it's not my job to do it for them, just to point them in the right direction. Your earlier comment was useful, this is not.

Comment: Muting/umuting would still get by the `if` statement. Even if the user already has permissions, excessive, unnecessary API calls will be made and could get the client rate limited.

Comment: That's true. And your answer is much better by far, without a doubt. But with the fixes, I disagree with the outright decision to downvote.

Comment: More code issues still remain present: `overwritePermissions()` should be called on a GuildChannel; there's no `message` parameter in a `voiceStateUpdate` event; the member would be denied permissions in the text channel upon joining the voice channel.

Comment: This is true. I apologize.